# Mysql Not Installing - Trying to Use it with RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the guides in a Lynda program teaching Ruby on Rails.

The guy suggests using mysql instead of using the default mysqlite3.

I ran this:

```
 rails new simple_cms -d mysql
```

and this is part of the error

```
An error occured while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: What would be the error if you ran `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` ?

Comment: No I ran this " rails new simple_cms -d mysql "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many people asking this question already.
If you are using linux,

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

If you are using mac, use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install mysql
```

then run gem install mysql2